# Error lateinit var has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I'm making the Github user search app [Search Github User App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z76M4.png) to practice parsing Json Api. Whenever I tried searching the username, the application crashes and return this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dicoding.picodiploma.githubappsub2, PID: 32607
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property data has not been initialized
        at com.dicoding.picodiploma.githubappsub2.main.MainViewModel.getData(MainViewModel.kt:17)
        at com.dicoding.picodiploma.githubappsub2.main.MainViewModel.searchUserInfo(MainViewModel.kt:59)
        at com.dicoding.picodiploma.githubappsub2.main.MainViewModel$searchUser$1.onResponse(MainViewModel.kt:29)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

It stated that lateinit property data has not been initialized when I'm trying to store data to a data class.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    adapter = UserAdapter()
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    viewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()
        ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    showLoading(false)
    recyclerViewSetup()
    searchUser()


}
private fun searchUser(){
    binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
            if (query.isEmpty()){
                return true
            }else {
                showLoading(true)
                viewModel.searchUser(query)
                getSearchedUser()
            }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
           return false
        }
    })
}

private fun getSearchedUser(){
    viewModel.getSearchedUser().observe(this, {
        if (it!=null){
            adapter.setData(it)
            showLoading(false)
        }
    })
}
private fun recyclerViewSetup() {
    binding.apply {
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(binding.recyclerView.context)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                binding.recyclerView.context,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
            )
        )
    }
}
private fun showLoading(state: Boolean){
    if(state){
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }else binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}
```

And here is the MainViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

val usersList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>>()
lateinit var data: User

fun searchUser(query: String) {
    RetrofitClient.githubApi.getSearchUser(query).enqueue(object : Callback<UserSearch> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserSearch>, response: Response<UserSearch>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val items = response.body()?.items
                val listTemp = ArrayList<User>()
                if (items != null) {
                    for (i in 0 until items.count()) {
                        val username = items[i].login
                        Log.d("Username", username)
                        val user = searchUserInfo(username)
                        listTemp.add(user)
                    }
                    usersList.postValue(listTemp)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserSearch>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Failure", t.message.toString())
        }

    })
}

fun searchUserInfo(username: String): User{

    RetrofitClient.githubApi.getUserDetail(username).enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
            val userInfo = response.body()
            Log.d("User Info", userInfo.toString())
            if (userInfo != null) {
                data = userInfo
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Failure", t.message.toString())
        }
    })
    return data
}

fun getSearchedUser(): LiveData<ArrayList<User>> {
    return usersList
}
```

Is there anything I did wrong in this code? How could I fixed it?
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`lateinit` lets you declare a variable without actually initialising it (by assigning a value) - you're promising to set a value on it before anything tries to read from it. But your code is trying to read from it

```
return data
```

before you've set a `User` on it

```
override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
    ...
    if (userInfo != null) {
        data = userInfo
    }
```

There's two problems - you're setting `user` in that `onResponse` callback, which is the result of a network request that's going to happen async, and come back later. You fire that off, and then hit `return data` long before the request returns to set the value.

The other issue is your `onResponse` code is only setting that value if `userInfo` isn't null - which means it might be null, which means `user` might not get initialised anyway (maybe never!)

---

`lateinit` is a good way to avoid making things nullable just for the sake of having an initial, throwaway value when you declare the variable. You can actually check if it's been initialised yet, with `::user.isInitialized`, but honestly this might be a good case for making `user` nullable - it's a property that you don't actually have a value for when this function is called, and maybe you never will.

Your `searchUserInfo` function has to at least be able to handle that possibility - right now it returns a `User`, which means it *definitely gives you a result*. But what is it meant to do if the search fails? Do you return a default `User`, or do you need a "no result" value, like null?

Comment: My idea was making the `searchUserInfo` return `User` then later, it will got stored to temporary holder `listTemp`. Then when it got called in `usersList.postValue(listTemp)` I expected that it post value from the data that are returned from the `searchUserInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `lateinit` in a ViewModel, because a ViewModel becomes usable once it's instantiated. This makes it possible for your `lateinit` properties to be accessed before they've been assigned. `lateinit` is for classes like `Activity` which do not become usable until after `onCreate` is called, so it is safe to leave values uninitialized until `onCreate` is called. Instead, you should make `data` nullable so the compiler will force you to check for it still being null when accessed.

In this case, your error is that you're returning `data` before it's every been assigned. You send off a Retrofit request but don't wait for the result before returning the uninitialized `data`. It doesn't make sense for `data` to be a property anyway, since it is unused anywhere outside your `searchUserInfo` function.

You can make `searchUserInfo` suspending and return nullable `User`, where a null value indicates a failure:

```
suspend fun searchUserInfo(username: String): User? {
    return RetrofitClient.githubApi.getUserDetail(username).await()
        .onFailure { Log.d("Failure", t.message.toString()) }
        .getOrNull()
        ?.let { it.body() }
        ?.also { Log.d("User Info", it.toString()) }
}
```

And then call the function from a coroutine. If you don't feel comfortable with coroutines yet, you can use a callback approach like this:

```
inline fun searchUserInfo(username: String, crossinline onSuccess: (User)->Unit){
    RetrofitClient.githubApi.getUserDetail(username).enqueue(object : Callback<User> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<User>, response: Response<User>) {
            val userInfo = response.body()
            Log.d("User Info", userInfo.toString())
            onSuccess(userInfo)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<User>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Failure", t.message.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Then, wherever you call it from, you pass a lambda that reacts to the returned User value.

Comment: Yes I'm not familiar with coroutines. So you mean I have to wait `searchUserInfo` to finish before calling it in the `searchUser` ? And what can I do to store the additional data to the User class without having temporary data holder like `listTemp`?